# C# / WPF - Data in list not appearing unless write-to-console call is present

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I am working on a C#/WPF project using Visual Studio Express for Desktop 2015.  I've found that a list of mine will not see the data it should contain unless I add a write-to-console call in order to determine if what I expect to see appears.  If I comment-out the write-to-console line the data no longer appears.  I find this odd and concerning.  The overall program is sort of large (at least I think so), so I will only post the method.

In our work locations laboratory setting Quality Assurance verifies working weights against primary weights to ensure the masses are comparable within a certain range.  This method generates a list of primary weights used during the verification test and creates a distinct list of serial numbers and correlating last calibration dates that will appear in the header section of the report.

I'm the only programmer/database person on my team, so I don't get to bounce these technical ideas off many people.  I appreciate any ideas to address this issue.

```
    private void GenerateSerialNumsAndLastCalibrationDates()
    {
        //In a lab setting Quality Assurance verifies working weights against primary weights
        //to ensure the masses are comparable within a certain range.  This method generates a list of primary weights
        //used during the verification test and creates a distinct list serial numbers and matching last calibration dates that will appear
        //in the header section of the report. 
        var primaryWeights = new ObservableCollection<Models.PrimaryWeight>(((App)Application.Current).PrimaryWeightsData.PrimaryWeights.OrderByDescending(x => x.NominalWeight).ToList());
        string serialNums = string.Empty;
        string calDates = string.Empty;
        List<Models.PrimaryWeight> chosenPWs = new List<Models.PrimaryWeight>();
        foreach (var wvl in ThisWeightVerificationReport.WeightVerficationLineItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WVL-PW count:" + wvl.PrimaryWeightsForVerificationLine.Count); //this line makes or breaks this method..don't know why???
            foreach (var pw in wvl.PrimaryWeightsForVerificationLine)
            {
                var foundPW = primaryWeights.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PrimaryWeightDbId == pw.PW_DB_ID);
                if (foundPW != null)
                {
                    chosenPWs.Add(foundPW);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Count of chosenPWs: " + chosenPWs.Count);//Without the make or break line above this returns as zero every time
        var finalPWs = (from w in chosenPWs group w by new { w.SerialNumber, w.LastCalibrationDate } into mygroup select mygroup.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("finalPW count: " + finalPWs.Count);//Without the make or break line above this returns as zero every time
        if (finalPWs.Count >= 1)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<finalPWs.Count;i++)
            {
                if(i==0)
                {
                    serialNums = finalPWs[i].SerialNumber;
                    calDates = finalPWs[i].LastCalibrationDate.DateTime.ToShortDateString();
                }
                else
                {
                    serialNums += ", " + finalPWs[i].SerialNumber;
                    calDates += ", " + finalPWs[i].LastCalibrationDate.DateTime.ToShortDateString();
                }
            }
        }
        //Must assign to Weight Verification Report Header
        this._wvr.VerificationHeaderInfo.PrimaryWeightSerialNumber = serialNums;
        this._wvr.VerificationHeaderInfo.PrimaryWeightCalibrationDates = calDates;
    }
```

Comment: Try replacing that line with `var xx = wvl.PrimaryWeightsForVerificationLine.Count;`. Maybe Count is realizing a query or something? Can we see code for `wvl.PrimaryWeightsForVerificationLine`? is `wvl.PrimaryWeightsForVerificationLine` in the ensuing foreach loop if you omit the WriteLine?

Comment: What are you seeing in the debugger when you step through it with and without the WriteLine call?

Comment: We would need to see PrimaryWeightsForVerificationLine class code. That seems off.